# How to recovery Apache on OS X Lion server?

Tags: osx-lion, apache-http-server, osx-server

The Apache has broken.

How to recovery it?

Can I delete the files in /etc/apache2,and then copy a new apache in it?

Comment: How is it broken? You can replace files as you wish. Note that not the whole server is in /etc/apache2.

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/apache2 folder contains the configuration files for Apache. If the change you made was to the configuration, you can simply fix the configuration file.

If you are looking for the binaries, you should look in the /bin or another folder that stores the Apache binaries (perhaps /usr/local or /usr/bin ?).